# Can I code Delphi apps in Windows and test them later n Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, delphi, cross-platform, delphi-10.2-tokyo

After several years away from Delphi (2006) I'm thinking about returning, to try cross platform Windows-OS X development. I have an old Mac Mini, dual booting Win10 and OS X. Everything I've found discussing cross platform Delphi involves configurations with the two OS's running simultaneously, either two machines or one machine+one virtual machine. (With 4G of RAM I don't think I have the memory for the latter option.)

I'm wondering if I could develop in Win10 (without MacOS running), compile, push to source control, etc. and then later pull the files to test in MacOS (without Win10 running)?

Comment: That would be a no. Delphi uses Xcode (on the Mac) to compile. Without the presence of Xcode, there's also no SDK available to compile with. Delphi requires a connection in order to compile for any Apple products. In any case though, I must warn you that Firemonkey is still relatively weak in OS-X. They're focused mostly on mobile, and lack some things when it comes to OS-X. The mobile side is maturing though.

Comment: You should have a mac with a windows virtual machine, then run delphi on it. Otherwise you could use windows with a VM and mac inside and then install a vm with win (inside the mac vm) but that's not the case.

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Why would you put a VM inside of a VM? That's absolutely not a requirement at all. You can do it either way around - in fact, you don't even need a VM. It's entirely optional, depending on your preference. If you have MacOS running on a VM in Windows, then simply connect your Delphi IDE to PAServer in that Mac VM.

Comment: @JerryDodge: " If you have MacOS running on a VM in Windows, "  Isn't that in violation of the Mac OS licence?  I thought it was only licenced to run on Apple hardware.

Comment: @MartynA Of course, that's a separate subject though :-) I'm just confused why anyone would want a VM inside of another VM, especially when two of them are the same OS.

Comment: @JerryDodge "but that's not the case". I've just told him what it's possible to do and I've suggested to AVOID the second scenario, then the decision is up to him. Currently I have the first setup (mac + windows wm)

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Then why even suggest it? That's not how I interpreted your comment - it didn't say anything about avoiding.   :-)

Comment: Why not, he is aware that the second option is possible but it's not good at all. And yes, actually mac os running on a VM is not very legal (...) :)

Comment: @Alberto I also don't see where OP is aware of or says anything about installing MacOS inside a VM on Windows. That originated from your comment, which is what sparked my confusion  :-)

Comment: From OP: I understand I could run Win10 inside a VM on the Mac, but I think doing so on an old Mac Mini (with 4G RAM) would be excruciating, at best.

Comment: Delphi can run in Windows 10 VM with 2 GB. The rest should be enough for OSX. If you don't have millions of lines of code to compile for your OSX application, you can probably make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build OSX applications on Windows without OSX connection with Delphi XE2-XE6.

Since Delphi XE7 OSX SDK and connection profile is needed for building the OSX applications.

Building or deploying OSX app doesn't work without active connection profile to OSX computer
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9492

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. Just as an FYI, the link you included requires a username and password.

Comment: You can use your Embarcadero account login and password. This is Quality Portal for reporting bugs and issues in RAD Studio, including Delphi. However, this is here more as FYI, hint that this behavior has been reported but unfortunately it has also been closed as designed. Besides that there is no further useful information there.